# Algorithm for allowing concurrent walk of a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, dependencies, graph-theory

In a directed acyclic graph describing a set of tasks to process, i need to find all tasks that can be processed concurrently. The graph has no loops and is quite small (~1000 nodes, ~2000 edges), performance is not a primary concern.

Examples with desired result:

- `[]` is a group. All tasks in a group must be processed before continuing
- `[x & y]` means `x` and `y` can be processed concurrently (x and y in parallel)
- `x -> y` means `x` and `y` must be processed sequentially (x before y)

**1**

[image: graph 1]

```
a -> [b & c] -> c
```

**2**

[image: graph 2]

```
[a & e] -> b -> c -> [d & f]
```

**3**

[image: graph 3]

```
[ [a -> b] & [e -> f] ] -> [ [c -> d] & g ]
```

I do not want to actually execute the graph, but rather build a data structure that is as parallel as possible, while maintaining the order. The nomenclature and names of algorithms is not that familiar to me, so i'm having a hard time trying to find similar problems/solutions online.

Comment: I think you should be more specific what you mean by "as parallel as possible". I would generally try to search for `dag scheduling` there are heaps of variants (most of them NP-complete). This [document](http://charm.cs.uiuc.edu/users/arya/docs/6.pdf) seems quite comprehensive. I get the point of your examples, but your decomposition in 3 would make `c` wait on `e -> f` even though that is not needed.

Comment: When i say "as parallel as possible" i mean that the as much progress can be done in parallel as possible. For example in the 3rd example, b doesn't need to wait for e to start processing.

Comment: If you want the plan with the shortest possible execution time, then this is easy.  Otherwise, it'll be hard on graphs, but probably easy if your input is really those expressions instead of general DAGs

Comment: Your examples are quite basic. What output would you expect for more interwoven graphs, like [this one](https://ibb.co/SfP36ZX)?

Comment: @MattTimmermans the inputs are general DAGs, not these examples. However, the same constraints apply. I'm not sure what you're referring to with "shorted possible execution time"?

Comment: @trincot [Image with same format as above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxmML.png). Following the format i specified above:
`a -> [ [b -> c -> e] & [d -> f] ] -> g -> h`
or
`a -> [ b & [d -> f] ] -> [ [c -> e] & g ] -> h`
The idea is that a task must wait on all dependencies before it is able to run. Any time more than 1 task is able to run, they run concurrently. As there are multiple solutions so this seems more like an optimization problem than i realized before. Here the first solution is slightly better as it allows `c` to start processing before waiting on `f`.

Comment: @Antti The problem is that in general when you push a DAG into your sequential format then you are going to lose some information (of the DAG) and therefore you will most likely also always have a non optimal schedule. In the exp just above `g` waits on `c->e` in the first solution and `c` waits on `d->f` in the second. So if you absolutely want this format then you need to define some metric what makes a solution better than another. For exp the number of violations just described or length of the sequence. Or you give us more constraints on the problem. For exp. the tasks have a unit length.

Comment: Your [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxmML.png) does not have the link `d->e` that I had in [my graph](https://ibb.co/SfP36ZX), which would make it more complicated (can you propose?) But yes: by condensing it to your desired output, you'll have to add more restrictions than are present in the original graph. In the first solution you provided, you leave `g` waiting for `e`, which really is unrelated to it. And in the second you leave `c` waiting for `f`... So, how many of such extra dependencies may be added to the problem before you would consider it unacceptable?

Comment: @rex123 I'm realizing that this problem is a bit more complicated than i initially anticipated. I don't have a good answer to what's better. Perhaps one metric would be to try to get the shortest possible length for the longest path, as the longest path would mean sequential steps.

Comment: @trincot Oh, i accidentally left out the `d->e` edge. [Updated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je7sq.png). It's true that this complicates it a bit further, maybe one solution would be `a -> [ [b -> c] & [d -> f] ] -> [e & g] -> h`. An unacceptable solution would be one that doesn't follow the original order in the graph, anything else is an improvement compared to processing all steps sequentially (we can assume infinite parallel processors for concurrent steps).

Comment: There is an interesting graph construction based on the Ishikawa graph, such that if solved for using min-cut/max-flow will yield a solution that satisfies the constraints for a set of labels along with minimizing the Total Variation in the set of assigned labels, which would yield a maximally parallel labelling in the sense mentioned above.

Comment: Would a solution assigning labels (meaning the same label can be executed in parallel) satisfying the dependency constraints while minimizing the total variation in the label assignment satisfying your needs? 

TV is more frequently utilized in denoising, but I believe it is applicable here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_denoising

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically, I would frame this problem as finding a minimally defined [series-parallel partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series-parallel_partial_order) extending the given partial order.

I would start by [transitively reducing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction) the graph and repeatedly applying two heuristics.

1. If x has one dependent y, and y has one dependency x, merge them into a new node z = [x → y].
2. If x and y have the same dependencies and dependents, merge them into a new node z = [x & y].

Now, if the input is already series-parallel, the result will be one node. In general, however, this will leave a graph that embeds an N-shaped structure like b → c, b → g, f → g from the last example in the question. This structure must be addressed by adding one or more of b → f, c → f, c → g, f → b, f → c, g → c. But in a different instance, this act would in turn create new N-shaped structures. There's no obvious notion of a closure, which is why this problem feels hard to me.

Some of these choices seem worse than others. For example, c → f forces the sequence b → c → f → g, whereas f → c is the only choice that doesn't increase the length of the critical path.

I guess what I'd try is,

3. If heuristics 1 and 2 have no targets, form a graph with edges x--y if and only if x and y have either a common dependent or a common dependency, compute the connected components of this graph, and &-merge the smallest component that isn't a singleton, followed by another transitive reduction.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution i came up with (pseudocode):

```
sequence = []
for each (node, depth) in depthFirstSearch(graph)
  sequence[depth].push(node)
return sequence
```

The `sequence` defines the order to process the graph. If an item in it contains more than one node, they can be processed concurrently.

While this allows for some concurrency, it does not advance as fast as it could. For example, `f` in the **3**rd example in the question would require `a` to be completed first (as it will be at depth 1, when `a` and `e` are depth 0). Ideally work on `f` could start when `e` is done.

Comment: depthFirstSearch does not seem to solve the 3rd example, long process a may run concurrently with both e and f.